# CiviCrm will not install on Joomla 3.5.0

Tags: installation

Installation fails with the following error using Joomla 3.5.0:

0 Call to undefined function dl()

Installation succeeds when using Joomla 3.4.8

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would highly suggest updating Joomla to 3.5.1 and then Civi to latest version. PLEASE backup, backup, backup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently running J 3.5.0 with CiviCRM v 4.7.4. Have you tried upgrading J 3.4.8 install to J 3.5.0? If not, I would give that a try.

Comment: I've got CiviCRM 4.7.10 running on J!3.6.2 without any issues.